# How to restrict text length of a extract in WordPress editor?

Tags: wordpress, filter

I need to limit the length of the excerpt field while writing a new post in WordPress. When the limit of characters or words is reached, I would like to show an error message and prevent the user from writing more input.

I found some hints but nothing with actual Wordpress versions. Where should I start to investigate, is there a filter to output a custom excerpt field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Code Under Them Button in tinymce Script.

and “id_txt” is your text area id

```
setup : function(ed) {
ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) {
txt = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

var strip = (tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()).replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,””);
var text =  strip.length + ” Characters”
tinymce.DOM.setHTML(tinymce.DOM.get(tinyMCE.activeEditor.id + ‘_path_row’), text);

id_txt = tinyMCE.activeEditor.id;
//alert (id_txt);
//strip the html
txt = txt.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,””);
txt = txt.replace(/&nbsp;/g,””);
if (id_txt == ‘blog_content’)
{

if (txt.length > 1000)
{
$(“#ErrorMsg”).css(‘display’,’block’);
$(“#ErrorMsg”).html(‘Please Enter Only 1000 Charecters !’);
txt = txt.substring(0,1000);
text =  1000 + ” Characters”;
tinymce.DOM.setHTML(tinymce.DOM.get(tinyMCE.activeEditor.id + ‘_path_row’), text);
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(txt);
ed.selection.select(ed.getBody(), true);
ed.selection.collapse(false);
return false;
}
}

/// Condition for Header Qutes

if (id_txt == ‘header_content’)
{
if (txt.length > 150)
{
$(“#ErrorMsg”).css(‘display’,’block’);
$(“#ErrorMsg”).html(‘Please Enter Only 150 Charecters !’);
txt = txt.substring(0,150);
text =  150 + ” Characters”;
tinymce.DOM.setHTML(tinymce.DOM.get(tinyMCE.activeEditor.id + ‘_path_row’), text);
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(txt);
ed.selection.select(ed.getBody(), true);
ed.selection.collapse(false);
return false;
}
}

});
}!
```